# Missing using directive or assembly reference in WPF in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

I am trying to draw a triangle in WPF in C# just to learn how to use this tool. If you check the last statement, I can't run program because of it. I think I am missing a using directive or maybe an assembly reference ...

These are the using directives I am employing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
```

Here is my code:

```
System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D point0 = new Point3D(-0.5, 0, 0);
System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D point1 = new Point3D(0.5, 0.5, 0.3);
System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D point2 = new Point3D(0, 0.5, 0);


System.Windows.Media.Media3D.MeshGeometry3D triangleMesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

triangleMesh.Positions.Add(point0);
triangleMesh.Positions.Add(point1);
triangleMesh.Positions.Add(point2);

int n0 = 0;
int n1 = 1;
int n2 = 2;

triangleMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(n0);
triangleMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(n1);
triangleMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(n2);

System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D norm = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
triangleMesh.Normals.Add(norm);
triangleMesh.Normals.Add(norm);
triangleMesh.Normals.Add(norm);

System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Material frontMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));

System.Windows.Media.Media3D.GeometryModel3D triangleModel = new GeometryModel3D(triangleMesh, frontMaterial);

triangleModel.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();

System.Windows.Media.Media3D.ModelVisual3D visualModel = new ModelVisual3D();
visualModel.Content = triangleModel;

this.mainViewport.Children.Add(visualModel); // here I have an error !
```

Comment: Where did you declare `mainViewport`? EDIT: I don't think the issue is that you're missing a `using` statement. I think the problem is that `mainViewport` has not been declared in an accessible scope.

Comment: I didn't declare it. I actually some 2 distinct tutorials saying that by just implementing this code, the program should work ... If I need to do that, how can I declare mainViewport?

Comment: Have you declared/named it in your XAML for the associated control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your xaml file overwrite your grid like this, and your black triangle will appear. i tested it.

```
<Grid>
        <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera 
  FarPlaneDistance="100"
  LookDirection="-11,-10,-9"
  UpDirection="0,1,0"
  NearPlaneDistance="1" 
  Position="11,10,9" 
  FieldOfView="70" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight 
    Color="White" 
    Direction="-2,-3,-1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I overwrote my grid in my xaml file, but weird enough, it's not working. This is the error message: " 'WpfApplication1.mainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'mainViewport' and no extension method for 'mainViewport' accepting a first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.mainWindow' could be found". It's weird because your declared in the second line "mainViewport" ...

Comment: Do I need to draw a triangle before running the application or should the triangle pop up by itself ?

Comment: ideally you would do it that way you tried, programmatically and outside of the xaml

Comment: ok, i see. But i still have the same error even when I overwrite my grid with what you wrote. My code doesn't recognize: this.mainViewport.Children.Add(visualModel); and the problem comes from "mainViewport" although it is defined in the Grid

Comment: @ahmad .... sure what is your email address (give me a spam one) and i will send u a zip of everything.   http://pastie.org/7900661

Answer (score 0):

It's bizarre, it doesn't work for me ! But if I replace the last statement by the following code, it shows no error since I declare mainViewport, but now when I run the program, the triangle doesn't show up ! (my xaml file looks just like the one written by Drew Pierce).

Any ideas why the triangle doesn't show up?

```
        System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Viewport3DVisual mainViewport = new Viewport3DVisual();

        mainViewport.Children.Add(visualModel);
```